# Response time for reasonable accommodation

Tags: americans-with-disabilities-act

An employee of a state government agency in the US submits a request for reasonable accommodation for a condition diagnosed by an LPC. After one month, the employee contacts the agency (in particular the attorney at the agency that handles personnel matters) and asks for an update. The attorney responds that they're still working on it. Three months have now passed since the original request.

The request it to work at home full-time, which the employee has been doing since the start of Covid.

EDIT:
https://www.justice.gov/usao/reasonable-accommodation-policy-and-procedure

2. Disposition and Provision of Accommodation

A final decision and provision of the accommodation should be made within 30 business days of the request, barring extenuating circumstances. Where an accommodation can be provided in less than the maximum time frame, failure to provide an accommodation in a prompt manner may result in a violation of the Rehabilitation Act.

How much time is the agency allowed?

Comment: What is an LPC?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=lpc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The agency is allowed a reasonable time to implement the request, given the nature of the request and surrounding circumstances. Superficially, it would seem that the request is to *continue* working at home as has been the case for a couple of years, so the agency would not seem to have to change anything in order to implement the request, and unnecessary delays would be a violation of ADA. There is no fixed time requirement for evaluating and implementing the request.